# What life (magical and non-magical) would survive and thrive in an air pocket under 1000 meters of water?

Tags: magic, science-fiction

## Background and Setup

--This is a fantasy world, where something to the tune of thousands of years have passed since a magical calamity occurred, giving rise to the creation of a magic dust (Vyxium), which, when mixed with water, makes it less dense than air suffused with Vyxium, which allows it to "float" on top of air pockets that were came to be at the time of the calamity. 

--The Vyxium-infused air quickly becomes toxic to humanoids, and most can only survive a number of days before losing higher brain function, and weeks before complete neural failure and death (if they manage to maintain their needs without higher brain function, which is unlikely). 

--Because the calamity was caused by magic users, they have been mostly ostracized from society, and have, in the millennia since the calamity, settled what were once prosperous cities with magical barriers against the Vyxium-infused air to make the area breathable, as well as magical lights to simulate a day/night cycle, and animals brought from the surface for those more interested in caring for creatures, rarely leaving these settlements.

### Question to be answered

I would like to know what realistic ***or*** fantasy based creatures would evolve to thrive in this environment without sunlight. These could be anything from insects to large monsters. 
 
***EDIT:***
---***CLARIFICATION,*** I'm looking for how the *biology* of these creatures would change in the given environment. For example, would they have the ability to see in the lack of light, or would they cease to have eyes all together? How would their bone structure change with the pressure of the water on top of them? Etc. 
---***REMOVED*** Ideation due to it confusing the meaning behind my question.

Comment: What life would you want to thrive there? It's up to you. It's not clear what you want as an answer. We like questions to have an identifiable best answer whereas this seems way too broad and opinion-based to fit with that. Can you tell us what your objectives are - what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: We're not here to tell you what fantasy based creatures exist in your world. As written it seems like you're asking us to brainstorm and generate ideas for you two activities that are against site policy.

Comment: @sphennings, and this answers angrymuppet as well, It's more about the biology of creatures that would exist in that environment. I.E, How would their bodies adapt to living under the pressure of tonnes of water, no light source, limited water supply, etc. I'll alter the post to better reflect this, it's my first time posting, so I don't quite have the hang of it yet.

Comment: Based on the one creature you have, lack of creativity is not your problem.  And in its description you note its prey including insects and deep fish.  Maybe work on those two?  The problem with dark is lack of plants and so I think you will need abundant fungi recycling the nutrients from the lit world that was.

Comment: We can't read minds. If you want to ask about how a creature will change ask about that. Be sure to edit your post to remove any other questions from earlier revisions because we have a strict one question per post policy.

Comment: "when mixed with water, makes it less dense than air suffused with Vyxium" - O_O this spells that if water is mixed with that vyxium, it floats above the atmosphere, provided vyxium fills the air. However, vyxium-free air should exist, thus there should be at least 4 layers in the "open air", from top to bottom: vyxium-ffree air, vyxium-filled water, vyxium-filled air, vyxium-free water, or two bottom layers could be swapped for a REAL trouble, as if vyxium won't be a trouble in itself. Is this so? If yes, there should be life between water, aaaand...

Comment: @Vesper The way it works in my headcannon is that Vyxium gives off a gaseous vapor that dissipates fairly quickly, but there is a large amount of it under the now Vyxium-infused oceans, causing this "air pocket" filled with highly toxic Vyxium gas. When Vyxium infused water evaporates, it loses its infusion with Vyxium, and goes through the water cycle, eventually falling back down as rain. This rain functions normally, except that when it falls on the Vyxium oceans, it agitates the water, effectively mixing it with Vyxium once again. In short - Vyxium-less water can only exist above sea level

Comment: This means your oceans are now completely infused with Vyxium, yet if water evaporates, Vyxium does not. How then Vyxium affects air above ground? From the looks of it, rivers should eventually have (or had already) moved all the Vyxium down into oceans or inland lakes. About air pockets - these exist on Earth, although gas in Earth's air pockets could be far from breathable.

Comment: I mean, microbes can survive in the deepest dark of the Mariana trench about 11, 000m, and life can adapt, scientists aren't all so sure about what alien life may lurk, we have only discovered 5% of the ocean. I suggest you look into speculative biology, play around with that and you may get some promising answers

Comment: @Vesper We're talking VAST quantities of this Vyxium and the gases it produces. This isn't a small pocket of air some feet deep, but rather the same ground that was once above water now below a plane of water. Fresh water and salt water both got contaminated, though most in the fictional world believe that the sea level just rose some thousands of feet. There is at least a thousand feet between the ground beneath the oceans and the ocean water. The only land that kept from being submerged were high altitude plateaus and mountains. Also, to reiterate, the Vyxium gas is far from safe to breathe.

Comment: I just looked into my notes for the world, and if you want exact figures, the surface of this new Vyxium-infused ocean sits at approximately 7,600 ft above the previous sea level, and is almost uniformly an approximate of 3,500 feet deep. Therefore, we're looking at approximately 4,100 feet of toxic gas between what was once the shoreline and the bottom of the floating ocean.

Comment: Wow that's some serious worldbuilding. Oceans that are really above the ground - these don't need anything like air pockets, they just cover the sky like clouds, but are instead solid liquid and a kilometer thick. This almost rules out any sunlight reaching the ground, also rules out any water circulation, as if any water drops from above, it gets infused with Vyxium and float upwards again. Same happens with ANY humidity below. Any water that remains Vyxium-free would either be stored underground without air access, or get infused and float upwards. Nothing carbon lives without water. Hum.

Comment: Also, what about ice (water ice)? How does Vyxium affect ice density?

Comment: @vesper So my general idea is that it is VERY cold beneath the floating ocean. So cold, in fact, that ice crystals begin to form on the bottom of the ocean. These ice crystals are heavy enough to fall through the Vyxium gas, making it so that there is a constant "snow" under the oceans. The planet, however, has fairly strong geothermal activity, meaning the ground is usually fairly warm. So the ice snows down, melts, and floats back up. So at any time you're working with a constant snow/reverse rain while under there. Also to clarify, Vyxium-infused water is non-toxic.

Comment: Hmm I'd say that there would be no ice under the ocean, as water above would sheath the lower layer from low temperatures. Thrre however would be ice in polar regions, that you say would freeze and drop throuh the floating ocean. Due to very slow energy flow through the rock, these would form polar caps directly on the surface, potentially this would thin out floating ocean over the millennia, provided there would be space to allocate all this ice. (Unlikely but still) So, the only place with water would be near there, everything else would still be dry.

Comment: Also you should calculate energy flow from geothermal activity via air convection to upper ocean, whether it would actually be enough to warm deep ocean layers to initiate convection within the ocean thus preventing any ice formed on the surface to reach ocean bottom or ground.

Comment: Welcome, please look over the [tag:magic] tag closely and understand that it is not compatible with sciences like [tag:xenobiology]. Magic is defined by you, the author, because it is not real and can do anything at all without being limited by nature. You must follow the tag rules and define the limits of your magic, or remove that tag before this can be opened again. Thank you.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but I would look into the possibility of the floating oceans losing their salinity. With limited contact  to the continental shelves and ocean floor minerals would not be replenished in the oceans at the same rates and may lose its salts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your world building essentially means that water goes above the air, making the new world contain three essential layers: Vyxium-free air, Vyxium-infused water, Vyxium-infused air. Given that any water that goes into contact with Vyxium-infused air gets lighter than it, any water that remains below ends up infused and floats upwards, forming an ocean above. Over the depicted years the Vyxium ocean would absorb any and all unprotected humidity located beneath it. Therefore, while life could still exist down there, it will not have access to fresh water, essentially eliminating all known life from the area below water level. Whoever remains above water, will see the planet's sea level rise to a new position, covering several miles of ground and making old mountains the only solid ground where to live, but unless they dive all the way down to Vyxium air level, they won't otherwise suffer any consequences.

Also, regarding water density in the ocean. You need to devise some numbers to which Vyxium alters density of air and water, then position the ocean at a level where Vyxium water density matches atmospheric density, and also consider that ocean volume would gradualy increase by such an action. Imagine Earth to suffer this calamity - the ocean is about 2 km deep if spread evenly over the geoid surface, and its density is 1035 kg/m^3. A Vyxium infuse of entire ocean would result in it having density of no more than 1.27 kg/m^3, resulting in it gaining 700x the volume - OW, a water sheath of 1400 km hardly allows for any land above, or light below. As an alternative, just the air could become heavier than water, but this would force the atmosphere to shrink at least 700x in volume, forcing whoever left above to suffocate during the initial mixing-up. Any intermediate value is allowed, with respective change to flotation abilities of sea life. For example, lowering water density by a factor of just 2 would make all fish drown, along with most kelp and other stuff, but if the Vyxium air would be at least as dense as water, the fish could actually swim in the air... quite a serious alteration, if you ask me, life does not evolve as fast to accommodate to such a change of the environment.

What about new life using Vyxium as solvent instead of water? Cannot say, as this is purely fictitional, but should there be enough oxygen below the ocean (which is possible, as if there is something breathing in the ocean, whatever they exhale underwater would become heavier than it and flounder downwards to the ocean-airbed, together with unprocessed oxygen, same goes to photosynthesis, if plants produce more oxygen than could be dissolved in the water), life can strive down there in almost complete darkness, maybe develop eyes in whatever wave range that passes through (water has some frequencies which it absorbs way less than average, and should Vyxium-infused water not get changed in this department, some light could still be shed on the waterless surface), mostly the vision would be monochrome as incoming light would be filtered by above ocean, leaving at most one frequency in a great range, but nothing sentient would appear after such a small time span genesis wise.

Regarding cities under magic domes - this is possible, if your magic users would happen to predict complete loss of water by the volume beneath the ocean and implement countermeasures within days before they plain dehydrate (which would result in death faster than neural degradation you describe, by the way!), then an oasis could be formed on the bedrock, hiding some survivors and maybe plants etc, yet the dome should be impenetrable to both air and water, or else whatever H2O your survivors would capture would be lost to Vyxium infusion and flotation. But there is another issue - the pocket would be pulled upwards by Archimedean force inflicted by the surrounding Vyxium air, which is proportionate to the volume of the dome. Should your air become heavier than water, the dome would pull upwards at 1000+ kgf per cubic meter, most likely detaching itself from the ground, thus those magic users would join the people on the above ocean side, and either suffer their fate, or adapt over the millennia and re-colonize.

**Summary**: Your scenario does NOT allow life to remain under such an ocean, and at the majority of parameter sets it also eliminates all life in the ocean and above. Bacteria would likely survive and adapt, but nothing more complicated than a polyp would remain alive.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a somewhat Earth-centric point of view. Oceanographers divide the ocean into zones as shown in the figure. With the pressure increasing about 1 atmosphere (14.7 psi) for every 10 meters of water. So the pressure is about 100 atmospheres or 1470 pounds per square inch. This of course is a lot, and the bends can be serious much shallower depths, so adaptations or ways to prevent the bends are of concern.

But for a lot of structures if the pressure is equalized on both sides it is not that much of a problem. On the other hand if have one side at low pressure and the other at 1470 PSI, then you need to understand how much area you have since the forces increase with area. So an open hull can ascend and decend without a lot of strong materials, but most modern submarines don't go to 1000 meters since they need to keep the interior at 1 atmosphere.

[image]

And at 1000 meters you could still claim to be on a continental shelf which would give you some geography to play with. It also means you can have bottom creatures as well as swimming creatures. There are deep water corals that have adapted to the cold and lack of light.

[image]

So it is pretty dark, almost completely so, but technically you are still in the twilight zone. It is really pretty dark at 200 meters, but there is enough light that big eyes are useful and even in the darker deeper regions some fish use bioluminescence to attract mates or prey.

And it is pretty cold, probably around 40 F, except maybe around some very localized  geothermal sources.

For ideas how mammals handle the pressure and the cold, take a look at elephant seals in particular. It is one of the [5 deepest diving animals](https://scubadiverlife.com/top-five-deepest-diving-animals/)

> Both species of elephant seal have a breath-hold time of more than 100 minutes. This makes their dives as remarkable for their length as they are for depth. Male elephant seals often dive for more than 60 minutes at a time, and the depth record for this species is an incredible 7,835 feet (2,388 m). Like the leatherback turtle and the emperor penguin, food is the incentive for the seals’ astonishing dives. They prey primarily on deep-dwelling species including skates, rays, squid and octopus. Elephant seals are a deep-diving success because their bodies hold an abnormally large volume of blood. This allows them to store additional oxygen. They also have increased levels of myoglobin, allowing them to store oxygen in their muscles, a larger percentage of oxygen-carrying red blood cells, and exceptionally thick blubber to protect them from the cold at depth.

So in general, there would be some pretty significant adaptations depending how much they spent out in the cold and pressure, and how much they needed to change depths, but probably a lot of earth sea life could point you to different adaptations you might want to have.